# what is the condition to return the items that doesn't match

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, filter, conditional-statements

```
const arr1 = ["605116", "703771", "726664", "612706", "475557", "521034", "547016"];
const arr2 = ["605116", "703771"];

arr1.map(item1 => arr2.map(item2 => (item1===item2) ? console.log(item1) : null))
```

result :

```
605116 703771
```

what is the condition to return the items that don't match?

expected results:

```
"726664", "612706", "475557", "521034", "547016"
```

need to be jsx compatible

Comment: BTW you are abusing `.map()` here. Please use a different array method for such a task, for example `.filter()`

Comment: that other example doesn't help i cant use for loops in jsx. The second map can be switched with a filter whatewer

Comment: You haven't mentioned anything about JSX. That is why you should always provide all the necessary details for others to be able to answer the question.

Comment: ok I edited now sry

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

```js
const arr1 = ["605116", "703771", "726664", "612706", "475557", "521034", "547016"];
const arr2 = ["605116", "703771"];

console.log(arr1.filter(item=>!arr2.includes(item)));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log(array1.filter(item => array2.indexOf(item) == -1));
```